# Calculate moving average by group/column - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, grouping, moving-average

I have a function that calculates an moving average. In the array i'm using there is a group variable (department) that in the present function are blurred together. I would like to do the ma-calculations by group instead. Is that even possible(**elegantly**, I might add. I could probably brute force it with my beginner-knowledge...)? I do some filtering later on (by department) but I would like to have the calculations done once and then be done with it.

Do anyone have an elegant solution? If there is a better way to do this than using map it's ok as well.

```
var movingWindowAvg = function (arr, step) {  // ma size = step
    return arr.map(function (_, idx) { 
        var wnd = arr.slice(idx, idx + step);
            var result = d3.sum(wnd.map(function(d) { return d.cases; })) / wnd.length; if (isNaN(result)) { result = _; };
            var nBeds= d3.sum(wnd.map(function(d) { return d.Beds; })) / wnd.length; if (isNaN(platser)) { platser = _; };
            var avd = wnd[0].Department;
            if (wnd.length < step) {
                console.log(wnd)
            }
            var tmpDate = wnd[wnd.length-1].datum; //Test to get the date-markers correct
            return {Cases: result, Date: tmpDate, Beds: nBeds, Department: avd, }; 
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I didn't find any good way to do this by group and it might be beneficial to have the un-edited values in the original ds (for example if I would like to make it possible to toggle ma or not)

This is the final code, i use slice to remove undefined objects afterwards:

```
var movingWindowAvg = function (arr, step) {  // Window size = step
    return arr.map(function (_, idx) { 
        var wnd = arr.slice(idx, idx + step);
        counter = Object_size(wnd);
        if (counter == step) {
            var result = d3.sum(wnd.map(function(d) { return d.persons; })) / wnd.length; if (isNaN(result)) { result = _; };
            var nbeds= d3.sum(wnd.map(function(d) { return d.beds; })) / wnd.length; if (isNaN(nbeds)) { nbeds= _; };
            var tmpavd = wnd[0].Dep;
            var tmpDate = wnd[step-1].datum;
            return {Persons: result, date: tmpDate, Beds: nbeds, Department: tmpavd , }; 
        }
    });
```

**Update, the Object_size function as well:**

```
Object_size = function(obj) {     
                var size = 0, key;     
                for (key in obj) {         
                    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
                    } return size; 
                };
```